# When exactly does React render -- problem managing state between various async calls, socketIO and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a MERN stack application with React as the front end.  It's a game that relies on socketIO to know when the other player has moved so that the game can do a REST API call from the DB to allow React to refresh the gameboard.

It works pretty well, but every once in a while the React app doesn't seem to receive the socketIO message, although, as I understand it, socketIO guarantees delivery. It's a hard bug to reproduce.  One idea was that React might be doing a refresh when the message arrived and that somehow screwed things up.  So I added a flag which I set to `true` when the message arrives, and clear the flag when the updated game is loaded, which I put into the React `state`, causing (I hope) a refresh.  The weird thing is that `render` is being called while the flag is still `true`.  Why is that?

In pseudocode

```
this.state = game
updateFlag = false

onSocketMessage => {
    updateFlag = true
    asyncGetNewGame
      .then(game => {
         updateFlag = false
         this.setState({game})
         })
   }

  render() {
     log.debug(updateFlag) // is true, but why?
     const {state:{game}} = this

     <SomeComponent game={game}>
  }
```

As per above, the flag remains `true` during the render, but I would think the synchronous setting of the flag to `false` after the async call to fetch the new game would happen *before* the render, because the render, as I understand it, is being caused by the change to the `state` field `game`, which I don't set until after I've changed the flag.

Am I understanding the timeline correctly?  If anyone could help shed some light on this I'd appreciate it.

Comment: don't you have another handler `onSocketMessage` for example in the parent component which could trigger a re-render ?

Answer (score 2):

Well, `setState` is NOT a synchronous method, so, any previous call to it might be triggering the render, not necessarily the one in `onSocketMessage`. Also, a modification to the component props might cause a re-render. If you want to follow a synchronous logic for `updateFlag` I suggest you using a callback: `setState(value, callback)`.

Also, notice this statement from [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> setState() will always lead to a re-render unless
>   shouldComponentUpdate() returns false. If mutable objects are being
>   used and conditional rendering logic cannot be implemented in
>   shouldComponentUpdate(), calling setState() only when the new state
>   differs from the previous state will avoid unnecessary re-renders.

So, if your logic depends on renders, then, it might be wrong as other things could trigger a re-render. And yes, socket.io guarantees packets/messages deliveries, but it does not guarantee other factors such as your logic, network status/configuration are fine. I suggest you to check out in the error events with your socket client and server if something has gone wrong.

Also, if your logic depends on specific state/props value changes, then you should use [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) for validations.

Hope I could help.